# find the limits of...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$A_n=\frac{cos(n)}{n}\to 0$$ I've been asked to find the limits of this sequence however using the sandwich theorem I have just found that the limit is $0$ is this the only limit if not what else is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$ (endowed with the usual topology), if a sequence has a limit, then it is unique.

Suppose by contradiction that you have a sequence $(x_n)_{n≥0}$ of real numbers that converges to $x$ and to $y$, with $y≠x$. WLOG you can assume $y>x$.

Let $\epsilon = \frac{y-x}{2}$. Then, by definition, then is $N$ such that $\forall n ≥ N, |x_n-x|<\epsilon$ and $|x_n-y|<\epsilon$

Therefore you get (using the triangle inequality) : $$|x-y|≤|x-x_N|+|x_N-y|<y-x$$ which is not possible.

NB : the uniqueness of limits is actually true for every [Hausdorff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space).